Having issues with Sim activation error
I'm having issues on my Redmi Note 10 5g, I'm unable to activate sim service, It's saying error everytime.

Sorry, as of current writing, it's unclear if the issue is about SIM card or if this is related to Android. If it's about Android, could you [edit] and clarify what you're trying to do, when this happened, and the exact error message?
